# Why is the owning window showing up above the owned window?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I have this very strange issue.  I'm trying to get a window hierarchy to be replicated.  So on creating the 1st level dialog, I'm start the instance of the 2nd level dialog.

I've done this in many different ways, but it always shows up as the 2nd level being below the 1st level and then usually a zorder inversion happens (they flip positions).  Occasionally, the inversion doesn't happen, but if I click on the owner, the owned immediately jumps to the top of the zorder.

Here are the main parts of a small example to show this happening:

```c++
const unsigned short WMA_DIALOGACTION        = WM_APP+1;
```

```c++
// Button event handler for the 0th level
void CdialogcallingdialogsDlg::OnBnClickedDlgLvl1()
{
    CDlgLvl1 x(this);
    x.DoModal();
}
```

```c++
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgLvl1, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED()
    ON_MESSAGE(WMA_DIALOGACTION, OnDialogAction)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CDlgLvl1::OnWindowPosChanged(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    if (!m_shownDlg) {
        m_shownDlg = true;
        PostMessage(WMA_DIALOGACTION);
    }
}

// Level 1 dialog opening up level 2 dialog
LRESULT CDlgLvl1::OnDialogAction(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    CDlgLvl2 x(this);
    x.DoModal();
    return LRESULT();
}
```

```c++
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgLvl2, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Level 2 dialog offseting its position
void CDlgLvl2::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpwndpos)
{
    ASSERT(lpwndpos->hwnd == m_hWnd);
    // Offset dialog to see the problem of dlg2 showing up below dlg1
    if (!(lpwndpos->flags & SWP_NOMOVE)) {
        lpwndpos->x += 10;
        lpwndpos->y += 10;
    }
}
```

In the example, you click on the button in the main dialog.  That then starts up `CDlgLvl1` which then starts up `CDlgLvl2`.  The dialogs are the default dialogs except for the message handling that is shown here and a button on the main application dialog.  If you look at it carefully, you can see the inversion.

What am I doing wrong?  Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

In case it makes a difference, the issue is more pronounced under Windows 10 and doesn't seem to be visible on Windows 8.1.

A copy of the solution can be pulled from my git repo here:

https://github.com/Ma-XX-oN/dialog-calling-dialogs.git

I've just added some bitmaps on the dialogs to really show the issue, but I've not tested on my 8.1 box yet.

I did a recording of how it pops up and here is frame 0, 2, and 3 of that recording:

Frame 0
[image: frame-0]

Frame 2
[image: frame-2]

Frame 3
[image: frame-3]

As you can see, LVL1 appears over LVL2 in Frame 2, and then flips position in Frame 3.

Full video can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BT9qqoBKay3LZQX1k8SVddwnMtb0lALd).

Using this example project, I've not been able to replicate LVL1 staying overtop of LVL2, but I believe that the behaviour of the zorder inversion not happening is some sort of race condition.

Comment: What is that `ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);` in `OnDialogAction()`meant to do?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a complete example .cpp I can paste into Visual Studio and compile?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, to bring up the that (1st level) window before showing 2nd.  Otherwise, it doesn't show up until the 2nd level window closes.

Comment: @selbie, I couldn't make that other git repo public, so I made one on github here: https://github.com/Ma-XX-oN/dialog-calling-dialogs.git

Comment: You should not need that `ShowWindow` call. Since LVL1 is modal and thus has focus in the app.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, well I do.  Removal of the `ShowWindow` call results in LVL1 not displaying until LVL2 has closed.  I can get around not using `ShowWindow` if I do things like using a timer to post a message to generate the LVL2 dialog, but the issue described still persists, and seems even more hacky.

Comment: Pls add the C++ tag to your question, so the code is properly highlighted.

Comment: Override `CDlgLvl1::OnInitDialog` and put `DWORD attrib = TRUE; DwmSetWindowAttribute(m_hWnd, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, &attrib, sizeof(attrib));` to make sure the `CDlgLvl1` is shown right away.

Comment: That's _very_ interesting @BarmakShemirani. So this points to a window manager issue.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused when windows "transition animation" is enabled. `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is being sent before the animation is finished.

To fix this problem, you can simply disable the transition for the dialog:

```
BOOL CDlgLvl2::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    BOOL attrib = TRUE;
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(m_hWnd, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, &attrib, sizeof(attrib));
    return res;
}
```

---

If you don't want to disable the transition, you have to wait until this transition is finished. I don't know how to detect it or how to determine the transition time. It seems to be 250 milliseconds. `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMENUSHOWDELAY...)` gives a value of 400 milliseconds which seems a bit too long.

Assuming we know the time, use `SetTimer` to run the function after transition is over:

```
BOOL CDlgLvl2::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    ANIMATIONINFO info = { sizeof info };
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETANIMATION, sizeof(ANIMATIONINFO), &info, 0);
    if (info.iMinAnimate)
        SetTimer(1, 250, nullptr);
    else
        SetTimer(1, 1, nullptr);
    return res;
}

void CDlgLvl2::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
    if(nIDEvent == 1)
    {
        KillTimer(nIDEvent);
        CDlgLvl2(this).DoModal();//note, PostMessage is not needed in SetTimer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your project in Visual Studio 2019:

[image: Results]

I ran it in DEBUG mode and it works fine. The third dialogue showed up as a child of the second dialog (that is, with the correct ZORDER). The same is true for RELEASE build.

See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f5z5ltq3vfc10r/Test.mp4?dl=0

## Update

If one of my classes I had a timer and I did this:

```
void CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    READYSTATE eState = READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED;

    if (nIDEvent == PRINT_PREVIEW_TIMER)
    {
        eState = m_pPrintHtmlPreview->GetReadyState();
        if (eState == READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        {
            KillTimer(m_uPreviewTimer);
            PostMessage(WM_COMMAND,
                MAKELONG(IDC_BUTTON_PRINT_PREVIEW2, BN_CLICKED));
        }
    }

    CResizingDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

You could adapt the principle and then just simulate pressing the button to display the second next dialog. Might work.

Comment: I didn't say that it the `third dialogue` wouldn't show `up as a child of the second dialog`.  However, did you notice the zorder inversion?

Comment: As I told you @Adrian, LVL2 shows up in front of LVL1. The ZORDER is correct. I can't get it to show up with the ZORDER incorrect, in both debug and release build.

Comment: Not even for a split second?  What OS are you running on?

Comment: @Adrian I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting.  What build?  `winver.exe` on my computer is giving me version 1809 build 17763.557.  Also the video seems to show the dialogs popping up very fast.  Have you done any modifications to your system?

Comment: @Adrian version 1903 build 18362.239. All I did was accept the upgrade when opening the project (toolset v142). No changes to code. But my PC is fast and has 16GB ram and the Graphics Card has a lot of memory.

Comment: Well, it's not a build environment issue.  Just tried VS2019 Preview latest build (upgraded just now).  Computer seems to be comparable, except my video cards are.  I have a bncmonitor driver plus a HD Radeon HD 8570 and an Intel(R) HD Graphics P530..

Comment: @Adrian another suggestion is to have a hidden button on lvl1. Then at end of oninitdialog in lvl1 post message to simulate pressing this button. The button handler displays LVL2.

Comment: When `OnInitDialog()` is called, the window is not displayed, so this won't work.  When you say simulate pressing the button, how do you mean?

Comment: @Adrian Something like `PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(IDC_BUTTON_XXX, BN_CLICKED),
    (LPARAM)m_btnXXX.GetSafeHwnd());`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is caused because the 1st level dialog creates the 2nd one before it has a chance to display itself. And yes, this can vary from system to system. There's no really a fix, but I would suggest a workaround, employing a timer. Below is some code.

**Header file for CDlgLvl1:**

```
class CDlgLvl1 : public CDialogEx
{
.
.
.
protected:
    UINT_PTR nIDTimer = 0; // Add this
};
```

**Source file for CDlgLvl1:**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDlgLvl1, CDialogEx)
    .
    .
    ON_MESSAGE(WMA_DIALOGACTION, OnDialogAction)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


BOOL CDlgLvl1::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    nIDTimer = SetTimer(1, 250, NULL);
    return TRUE;
}

void CDlgLvl1::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (nIDTimer && nIDEvent == nIDTimer)
    {
        KillTimer(nIDTimer);
        nIDTimer = 0;
        PostMessage(WMA_DIALOGACTION);
        return;
    }

    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}

LRESULT CDlgLvl1::OnDialogAction(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CDlgLvl2 x(this);
    x.DoModal();
    return 0;
}
```

The mechanism you provided to prevent the 2nd window being displayed multiple times (the `m_shownDlg` variable) has been replaced by the `nIDTimer` check.

Please experiment with the timer's elapse value. The one I suggest (250 - 1/4 sec) is OK for most systems and imperceptible to to the user.

I wrote this in the SO editor, no actual test in VS (so it may contain some few syntax errors - pls fix them if so).

**Note:** You do not need to override `OnWindowPosChanging()` if you only want to set the position of the 2nd dialog. It's relative to its parent, so you can simply set the `X Pos` and `Y Pos` properties of the dialog's resource.

Comment: Why not just test if the parent dialog handle is valid, that the dialog is visible. If both are true then send the message to show the second dialog. Otherwise, continue the timer.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried to use that, but it's kludgy and can be unstable depending on the speed of the computer.  Thanks for the Note though.  Didn't realise that it could be done in the dialog editor.